# How to code a back button on the a navigation bar using a bar button item

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm having trouble coding a button to go to the previous page.  I was able to do it to go to the next page thinking if I did the same thing but changed it a bit it would work in reverse.  Unfortunately, I come up with a lot of errors I can't resolve because it won't allow me to use the release function.
This is this the code that helps it to work going to the next page fine:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id) sender
{
    //add the view of the view controller to the current View---
    if (menuView==nil) {
        menuView = 
        [[MenuView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView"
                                   bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:menuView.view];

}
-(void)dealloc {
 [menuView release];
 [super dealloc];
}
```

How do I do it so that a back button will go to the previous page though.

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController` to control the stack?

Comment: I am not.  I'm using a UIViewController.  I'm new to this so sorry if this is a stupid question Paul, but can I use both controllers at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, use this :

```
-(IBAction)back:(id) sender
{
    [menuView.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But, I would suggest not using `addSubview:` for many views as it would be complex way to do. Use `UINavigationController` as @Paul.s suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this is not quite correct and I would suggest doing some reading to get familiar with iOS programming.

Your program structure should be: create a navigation controller (2) to manage the stack of view controllers giving it a viewController (1) to act as it's root.

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // 1
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    // 2
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    [firstViewController release]; firstViewController = nil;

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [navigationController release]; navigationController = nil;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This will display your first view controller inside a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). A [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is responsible for managing a stack of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s and giving you UI to navigate back down the stack as well as calling all the appropriate presentation related methods on a [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) at the correct times e.g. `viewDidLoad`. You should check out [The View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1) for lots of info

Then inside your first view controller you do something like this to respond to the button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [secondViewController release]; secondViewController = nil;
}
```

This creates a new view controller and pushes it onto the stack.

Comment: Oh ok.  I'll go back and re-create my file using a UINavigation Controller first instead.  Thank you Paul.